# Regex for sentences and apostrophe?

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that would allow me to write any sentences like this "I didn't like the customer's view", so one that includes any words with an apostrophe like "don't, customer's" and not just names, but full sentences.

This one doesn't seem to work ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s_,"':öäëïüéáß?!-.]{1,1000}$

Any idea please?

I tried this one ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s_,"':öäëïüéáß?!-.]{1,1000}$
But it keeps on being refused.

Comment: Do you need to escape the `-`? Like this: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\s_,"':öäëïüéáß?!.]{1,1000}$`

Comment: For what flavor of RegExp are you looking for a solution? Can you provide a few more sample inputs and outputs for clarity?

Comment: Everytime I try to type an answer to the question set with the regex given, I get a message that my reply is not valid and can't continue further
However, when I retype my answers without the apostrophe, so let's say "don't" becomes "do not", only then my reply is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pre-defined character classes instead of spelling out language specific characters:

```
^[\w\s']+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Su29az/1)

Comment: Hello! Thank you! I have tried, but it fails to work again.

Comment: There is a demo link in the answer, so there's no such thing as "it fails to work".

Comment: I checked the demo indeed. But I mean when I put that regex in our system it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for multiple sentences:

```
^(?:[\w\s'’`]+[\s\.\!\?]*\s*)*$
```

And you can easily specify any apostrophe or other special symbols in first square brackets.

Comment: Thank you! I have also tried that one, but it doesn't work.

When I put "don't" for instance, it refuses it. But when I say "do not", then it accepts it.